# Interfacing with the Commodore 64 IEC Serial Port using Assembly

Tags: commodore-64, assembly, 6502, serial

I'm struggling a bit to find relevant documentation on this subject when it comes to using just assembly. All I've found is either irrelevant or for BASIC. My goal is to be able to send and receive strings from the C64 IEC serial port, but I cannot find literally any documentation on kernal subroutines, instructions, or examples.
The documentation on the IEC serial port is useful for seeing how it works in terms of electronics, but I either found it too difficult to parse or there's no information on programming it with assembly.

Comment: Are you asking for "user port serial" or "IEC-bus serial" connections - The C64 actually has more than one serial port which are handled largely different.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm talking about the IEC-bus. @tofro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IEC kernal (sic!) routines can be found at $ed00, and the RS232 kernal routines at $eeba. Michael Steil has built a very nice [side-by-side table of 5 different commented disassemblies](https://www.pagetable.com/c64ref/c64disasm/) which, taken together, should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to navigate the kernal source. Whereabouts is $ed00

Comment: You can find the adresses on the very left, white on blue. The easiest way to get to a specific address is to use your browser's search function, typically `Ctrl` + `F`, and search for `:ED00`.

Comment: It may be helpful to add as well a few links with background information beside just reading source code. For example a [hig level overview of the Kernal](https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Kernal) and Jim Butterfields Compute! article about the [basic protocol](https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:how_the_vic_64_serial_bus_works), or [this nice write up](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/programming/serial-bus.pdf).

Comment: @SkyeG06 Rather than using the routines starting at `$ED00`, you should use the ones in @Raffzahn 's first link. These are the official kernal routines. If you look for them in the disassembly listing (they start at address `$FFA5`) you'll see that they are properly documented, although on my browser the documentation column seems to be one row out of sync with the disassembly.